# rosdep basic usage

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a couple packages that depend on python libraries ( one depends on rtklib and the other on mxnet)

My first question is do these belong in my package.yml file

```
  <build_depend>rtklib</build_depend>  
  <run_depend>rtklib</run_depend>
```

and

```
  <build_depend>mxnet</build_depend>  
  <run_depend>mxnet</run_depend>
```

I'm trying to get the hang of rosdep by doing a simpler example with pygame. I included

```
 <run_depend>pygame</run_depend>
```

in my package.yml and then ran `rosdep install <my-package>`

but I get the error:

> ERROR: the following packages/stacks
> could not have their rosdep keys
> resolved to system dependencies:
> rosdep_tutorial: Cannot locate rosdep
> definition for [pygame]

I also tried python_pygame but that did not work either

**UPDATE:**
Okay, I got my pygame example working by using python-pygame because I found out that rosdep is using the apt package manager. Now I'm stuck because neither rtklib or mxnet are able to be install via apt. How should these be installed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260493/rosdep-basic-usage/) by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 545 on 2017-04-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rosdep resolves to local ROS packages, entries in an active rosdistro, or by using the rosdep [rules set](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/tree/master/rosdep)

python-pygame works because it's already in the rules: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/python.yaml#L1959

If you package is not in that set you need to add a local rosdep rule source or submit one upstream.

You can contribute new rules following this procedure: http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosdep/html/contributing_rules.html

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0